# Nuevas reglas css al finalizar una animación CSS3

Tags: css3

Es posible que tras finalizar una animación personalizada con keyframes pueda cambiar las propiedades de un elemento (¿Es posible sin usar JS?).

Por ejemplo, al finalizar una animación pasar a `display: none;` para ocultar el elemento.

Por el contrario, partir en `display: none;` y terminar en un `display: block;` para que el elemento quede visible permanentemente tras la animación.

Hablo de la propiedad display a modo de ejemplo, mi consulta es un poco más general ya que quisiera saber si es posible modificar otras propiedades de elemento como width, height, etc.

```
div#jeje{
    -webkit-animation: custom 1s ease-out;
    -ms-animation: custom 1s ease-out;
    -o-animation: custom 1s ease-out;
    animation: custom 1s ease-out;
  }

  @keyframes custom {
    0%{
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    50%{
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px -20px #888888;
    }
    100%{
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puede usar:

```
animation-fill-mode
```

para definir que valors tendrá el elemento al finalizar la animación

Answer (score 0):

Con `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` mantengo el ultimo estado de la animación.

```
div#jeje{
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: all 3s ease;
    -webkit-animation: custom 1s linear;
    -ms-animation: custom 1s linear;
    -o-animation: custom 1s linear;
    animation: custom 1s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

@keyframes custom {
    from,0%{
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }

    50%{
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px -20px #888888;
    }
    90%{
      background-color: yellow;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

Podría hacer que acabe la animación en 99% y el 100% serian mis nuevas reglas css (deben ser atributos con valores numéricos).